# Adding related object fields on to the parent

Tags: apex

Apex code based on following senario.

- List item
  Opportunity and competitor hold master relation ship. 
  competitor holds fields like primary checkbox,competitor Machine(Picklist),Competitor Name.
  If primary competitor == true then the corresponding Machine,Competitor Name has to be populated on Opportunity in the field Primary competior<---Name and Primary

Competitor Machine <--- competitor Machine.
and here is my code

```
public with sharing class CompetitorTriggerHandler {

  // update the primary competitor,Primary Machine when new records are inserted from trigger
  public void OnAfterInsert(List<Competitor__c> newRecords){
    updatePrimaryCompetitor(newRecords); 
    updatePrimaryCompetitorMachine(newRecords); 
  }

  // update the primary country primary Machine when records are updated from trigger  
  public void OnAfterUpdate(List<Competitor__c> oldRecords, 
      List<Competitor__C> updatedRecords,  Map<ID,Competitor__C> oldMap, 
      Map<ID,Competitor__C> newMap){
      updatePrimaryCompetitor(updatedRecords); 
   updatePrimaryCompetitorMachine(updatedRecords); 

  }

  // updates theopportunity with the primary competitor and primary competitor Machine 
  private void updatePrimaryCompetitor(List<Competitor__C> newRecords) {

    // create a new map to hold the opportunity id / competitor values
    Map<ID,String> OpportunityCompetitorMap = new Map<ID,String>();
    Map<ID,String> OpportunityPrimaryCompetitorMap = new Map<ID,String>();
    // if an competitor is marked as primary, 
    // to the map where the opportunity id is the key 
    for (Competitor__c com : newRecords) {
      if (com.Primary_Competitor__c)
        OpportunityCompetitorMap.put(com.Opportunity,com.Name);
        OpportunityCompetitorPrimaryMap.put(com.Opportunity,com.Competitor_Machine__c);
    } 


    // query for the sal in the context to update
    List<Opportunity> orders = [select id, Primary_Competitor__c,Primary_Competitor_Machine__c from Opportunity where id IN:  OpportunityCompetitorMap.keyset()];


    // add the primary country to the sales order. find it in the map
    // using the sales order's id as the key
    for (Opportunity so : orders)
      so.Primary_Competitor__c = OpportunityCompetitorMap.get(so.id);
   so.Primary_Competitor_Machine__c = OpportunityCompetitorMap.get(so.id);
    // commit the records 
    update orders;

  }
}
```

error: variable  so.Primary_Competitor_Machine__c does not exist.
i cross checked the API name and this field was present on layout too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the scope of the `so` variable.  It is not visible in the line that you are getting the error.  The `so` variable is declared in the for loop and is only visible in that for loop.  Since you don't have braces to define the boundaries of the loop, only the one line that directly follows it is part of it.

Change your loop to include braces:

```
for (Opportunity so : orders) {
    so.Primary_Competitor__c = OpportunityCompetitorMap.get(so.id);
    so.Primary_Competitor_Machine__c = OpportunityCompetitorMap.get(so.id);
}
```

You currently have the following:

```
for (Opportunity so : orders) 
  so.Primary_Competitor__c = OpportunityCompetitorMap.get(so.id); // part of loop
  so.Primary_Competitor_Machine__c = OpportunityCompetitorMap.get(so.id); // not part of loop
```

Also, you have the following code which causes the error

> Invalid field opportunity for sobject competitor

```
OpportunityCompetitorMap.put(com.Opportunity,com.Name);
OpportunityCompetitorPrimaryMap.put(com.Opportunity,com.Competitor_Machine__c);
```

The issue with that code is that a custom object field must end in `__c`, so the references to `com.Opportunity` should be changed to `com.Opportunity__c`.

Comment: .Thank you.  i'm trying to put values from competitor on to opportunity at lines   OpportunityCompetitorMap.put(com.Opportunity,com.Name);
        OpportunityCompetitorPrimaryMap.put(com.Opportunity,com.Competitor_Machine__c);      error:invalid field opportunity for sobject competitor.

Comment: @Sindoora - Updated the answer. Good luck!  It looks like you are close. :)

Comment: One step a head .

Comment: Thank you. output i can see that it is pushing competitor machine into both the fields
(primary competitor,primary competior machine)  output should be: Name ----> Primary competitor ; Competior Machine ----> Primary Competitor Machine.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  See the [Apex Map documentation here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm) for how to use Maps.

Comment: @Sindoora - Awesome!  Glad to help. :-)